# Making a Comment on a page without being on that page?

Tags: comments, comment-form

I have a built a Wordpress site that enables comments on pages and I am using them as *reviews*, what I would like to do is for someone to be able to make a comment on a page without being on that page.

http://universitycompare.com/university-guide/anglia-ruskin-university/

On the link above, the top right, there is a link that says ***have your say about a university***, it would be good to have a HTML form and then a dropdown box of all the child pages of **university-guide**; which is where all the universities are stored, and then I can put my comments.php file into this.

So my HTML form appears and when a page is picked from a dropdown box, the comment will then be assigned to that page.

Any help or direction?

---

New Question for Toscho:

Below is your tweaked plugin to fit into my website, as you can see I have added the select option **yearSelect** and need this to appear when the comments appear. How would I go about doing this? - Could you provide ay help please?

```
    <?php
/* Plugin Name: haveyoursay */

/**
 * Call the form in your template with:
 * do_action( 'wpse_67527_comment_form' );
 */
add_action( 'wpse_67527_comment_form', 'wpse_67527_comment_form' );

/**
 * Create a review form.
 *
 * @return void
 */
function wpse_67527_comment_form()
{
    $select_id = 'page_select';
    $url = 'http' . ( is_ssl() ? 's' : '' ) . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $url = esc_url( $url );
    ?>
<form action="<?php echo site_url( '/wp-comments-post.php' ); ?>" method="post">
<h3>Leave us your student perspective <img src="/wp-content/themes/blue-and-grey/images/hmepage-tri.png"></h3>
    <p>
        <label for="author"><?php _e( 'Name' ); ?></label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input id="author" name="author" type="text" size="40" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="email"><?php _e( 'Email' ); ?></label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input id="email" name="email" type="text" size="40" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $select_id; ?>">
            <div class="clear"></div>
            Pick a university from the list: &nbsp;&nbsp;
        </label>
        <?php
        // Ordered by page name automatically
        wp_dropdown_pages(
            array (
                'name' => 'comment_post_ID',
                'id'   => $select_id,
                'child_of' => 2,
            )
        );
        ?>  
    </p>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <p style="margin:10px 0px 0px 0px;">Please select your year of study: &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <select name="yearSelect">
    <option value="1st">First Year</option>
    <option value="2nd">Second Year</option>
    <option value="2nd">Third Year</option>
    </select>
    </p>
    <br />
    <p>
        <textarea name="comment" cols="45" rows="8"></textarea>
    </p>
    <p>
        <?php
        wp_nonce_field( 'unfiltered-html-comment_' . get_the_ID(), '_wp_unfiltered_html_comment_disabled', FALSE );
        ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?php echo $url; ?>" />
        <input type="submit" style="margin:15px 0px 0px 0px; padding:4px 10px;" />
    </p>
</form>
    <?php
}

add_filter( 'comment_post_redirect', 'wpse_67527_redirect' );

/**
 * Strip '#comment-number' from redirect url.
 *
 * @param  string $url
 * @return string
 */
function wpse_67527_redirect( $url )
{
    $parts = explode( '#', $url );
    return $parts[0];
}
?>
```

Comment: Do not change the meaning of a question after it was answered. That’s very hard to understand. Ask a new question instead.

Comment: @toscho - okay, I will go back to the original question I asked and delete the 'new' stuff above. here is a link to my new question: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67570/how-to-add-an-extra-form-select-in-comments-and-display-the-outcome - would appreciate any help you may be able to offer if you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the value of `$_POST['comment_post_ID']` to the post id of the page:

```
<input type='hidden' name='comment_post_ID' value='10' />
```

Then set the `action` of the form element to `/wp-comments-post.php`, filter `'comment_post_redirect'` and send the visitor back to page where the comment/review was written.

Here is an example, written as plugin:

```
<?php
/* Plugin Name: Comment on different page */

/**
 * Call the form in your template with:
 * do_action( 'wpse_67527_comment_form' );
 */
add_action( 'wpse_67527_comment_form', 'wpse_67527_comment_form' );

/**
 * Create a review form.
 *
 * @return void
 */
function wpse_67527_comment_form()
{
    $select_id = 'page_select';
    $url = 'http' . ( is_ssl() ? 's' : '' ) . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $url = esc_url( $url );
    ?>
<form action="<?php echo site_url( '/wp-comments-post.php' ); ?>" method="post">
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $select_id; ?>">
            Choose a page
        </label>
        <?php
        // Ordered by page name automatically
        wp_dropdown_pages(
            array (
                'name' => 'comment_post_ID',
                'id'   => $select_id,
                            'child_of' => 2,
            )
        );
        ?>
    </p>
    <p>
        <textarea name="comment" cols="45" rows="8"></textarea>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="author"><?php _e( 'Name' ); ?></label>
        <input id="author" name="author" type="text" size="30" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="email"><?php _e( 'Email' ); ?></label>
        <input id="email" name="email" type="text" size="30" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <?php
        wp_nonce_field( 'unfiltered-html-comment_' . get_the_ID(), '_wp_unfiltered_html_comment_disabled', FALSE );
        ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?php echo $url; ?>" />
        <input type="submit" />
    </p>
</form>
    <?php
}

add_filter( 'comment_post_redirect', 'wpse_67527_redirect' );

/**
 * Strip '#comment-number' from redirect url.
 *
 * @param  string $url
 * @return string
 */
function wpse_67527_redirect( $url )
{
    $parts = explode( '#', $url );
    return $parts[0];
}
```

I called the action with:

```
is_front_page() and do_action( 'wpse_67527_comment_form' );
```

… on the `index.php` and got a simple comment form that sent its content to another page. :)

Comment: wow! pretty good tosco! I'm going to give that a try now, now with the label's etc I can add them and have them display as part of the comments right?

Comment: must say! Brilliant plug-in and something I am really happy with! - Cannot thank you enough, but is there a way that it can only display the child pages of the page id '2' - How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Look up [`wp_dropdown_pages()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_pages): the parameter `child_of` will do what you need.